# Combine multiple rows in database of millions

Tags: mysql

I have a table with millions of rows structured as follows:

```
UserID | Date       | Points
1      | 2016-05-01 | 240
1      | 2016-05-02 | 500
1      | 2016-05-03 | 650
2      | 2016-05-01 | 122
2      | 2016-05-02 | 159
2      | 2016-05-03 | 290
```

And so on and so forth.

I need to find the difference in `Points` between `2016-05-03` and `2016-05-01` for each ID, sort by that difference in `Points`, and return the top ~100. My database contains hundreds of millions of rows, so it needs to be a speedy operation.

Where would I begin? I was looking at `group_concat` but I'm unsure if that's the correct function for this use case.

Comment: Are these dates `2016-05-03 and 2016-05-01` static for all userIDs ?

Comment: @bhantol They are, yes. Each user will have an entry for both dates.

Comment: Does table have primary key column?

Answer (score 0):

This query is working, it is not very much speedy but can be made.

```
select tbl.id as UserId, ((select t.points from tbl t where date = '2016-05-03' and t.id=tbl.id)-(select t.points from tbl t where date = '2016-05-01' and t.id=tbl.id)) as diff from tbl group by id order by diff limit 100;
```

Run this and let me know if this is taking much time.

Answer (score 0):

You should have subquery like below

```
SELECT 
     user_id,
     (select points from tbl_test where tbl_test.date_of='2016-05-03' and user_id=t1.user_id)-t1.points as difference_in_points 
FROM `tbl_test` as t1 
WHERE date_of='2016-05-01' order by difference_in_points desc 
limit 100
```

Comment: is this helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself.

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.points - t2.points as diff
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.date = '2016-05-03'
AND t2.date = '2016-05-01'
ORDER BY diff DESC
LIMIT 100
```